# Is there any tests for android similar JUnit for Java?

Tags: android

Is there any tests for android  similar JUnit for Java ? Does anybody have experience with this ?

Answer (score 5):

**JUnit** is also the de-facto standard for testing on **Android**. You can find some documentation at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/testing/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

I use JUnit with jmockit to test against android libraries:

https://github.com/ko5tik/andject/blob/master/src/test/java/de/pribluda/android/andject/ViewInjectionTest.java

Mocking is necessary because android libraries are just stubs good for nothing but compiling 
against them. Provided examplr runs tests from maven build as well as from eclipse / idea